# Cannot Send Tweet popup appears

Tags: ios, twitter

I added Twitter to my iOS app. I'm using iOS 5's TWTweetComposeViewController in ShareKit. It returns TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone. So ShareKit gets to sendDidFinish, and thinks the tweet was successful. It exits smoothly out.

Then after < 1 minute, Apple displays a message:

"Cannot Send Tweet"

"The tweet, "blah blah blah" cannot be sent because the connection to Twitter failed."

I'm in China, and I turned off the VPN, so technically the message is correct. However, how do I know that I'm going to get this message? How do I know if the tweet is finally posted? that way I can keep the "loading" icon still rotating in the background. Is there a notification message that I can listen for?

Thank you

Comment: Really Interesting Question.Hope to see some answers.I will give you upvote..

Comment: This problem happens on Apple's Twitter sample code too. It says the tweet is done, then minutes later the "Cannot Send Tweet" popup appears. Apple's Twitter framework is missing additional error checks and notification messages. I hope they fix it in next SDK release.

Comment: May be.But let's see will you get some answers or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if this is related, but in simply trying to send a tweet today via Safari on the iphone I got the "Cannot Send Tweet" message.  Some experimentation revealed that the tweet was too long.  The tweet contained a link, which Twitter automatically shortens and calculates for in the amount of characters left that it displays for your tweet.

Looks like Apple is calculating this incorrectly, because although my tweet showed 3 characters remaining in Safari's tweet bubble pop-up, when I pasted the same information into the iphone Tweeter app, it was over the limit.  Once shortened it posted fine from Safari.

So I would say Elissa Tong is right - "Apple's Twitter framework is missing additional error checks and notification messages."

Comment: Whoops, meant to post that as a comment to the OP not an "answer". My bad.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: There is some aspect to this other than length - desktop Safari is failing like this every time for me at the moment, regardless of length. That likely still comes under "missing additional error checks and notification message though".