# iOS Twitter post issue - number of characters

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

As I know the max length of characters for twitter post is 117. When I post plain text. it's no problem. But when I add a text for hyper link, it will cause problem when I post 117 characters (I can reduce the total length in order to post successfully). Why is like that?

Plain text:

[image]

Text with url inside:(this will cause problem even there are 3 characters remains. But if I keep reducing the characters. For example, 10 characters left, then I can post successfully)

[image]

Error:

[image]

I think the Twitter count algorithm is different from iOS. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837285/cannot-send-tweet-popup-appears

Comment: Thanks. I know the problem. But I need a solution. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out finally. My conclusion:

1. The maximum length of twitter text is 140 in web, 117 in iOS if there is no url inside.
2. The length of each url is 23 no matter original length of the url is. So you have to calculate the maximum length of text allowed by yourself.

Refer to https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text for details although the max length in ObjC is wrong.